# Android Studio having an error when implementing play-services (mediarouter)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have implemented *com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1* in my new project. It shows an error after I have synced the gradle.

[image]

Then I implemented *com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0-rc02* from project structure. It was okay after that. When I did that to media-router, It didn't work. It showed a dialog that I need to download it but after downloading nothing is happening.

What I have done:

1. I tried looking in the build.gradle but the error is still there.
2. I tried to import it again but it just prompted me again to download, then same thing happened.

Comment: you have to use same version for app support and for support design for both the version should be same and its not an error it a warning

Comment: give same version to mediarouter

Comment: I tried to create a new project again, at first there's no warning. But when i implemented play-services from project structure that warning pops up.

Comment: you can ignore it

Comment: ok thank you @Faiz Mir

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is not an error, it's a warning. You can still compile and run your app. But it is **recommended** by google to keep all support libraries of the same version to avoid runtime crashes.